# How to play Vimeo Video Url in iOS app

Tags: avfoundation, media-player, avplayer, swift4

I am not able to play vimeo video url using AVPlayer in swift 4 and below code for I am using :

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: self.trailerVideoURL)!)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player
present(playerController, animated: true) {
    player.play()
}
```

Comment: Why are you *"not able to play"* the video? Do you get an error? If so, please post it here as well.

Comment: Yea, what is your error?

Comment: Not any error just play button with slash over it